Count number of occurrences of same value over multiple tables with different column names
this is the problem. I have two tables - ps5 and xbox:-



id
ps5_game




John
COD


Jean
GTA


Kash
COD


Don
PVZ


Trey
GOW


Nate
UC






id
xbox_game




Jarvis
UC


Carl
GOW


Damon
COD


Donny
GOW


Trav
GOW


Natty
UC



Now, I need to get the number of times of occurrences of each of the values in ps5_game and xbox_game spread over two tables, sorted in descending order. The values under id don't matter. The expected result is somewhat like this:-



game
occurrence




GOW
4


COD
3


UC
3


GTA
1


PVZ
1



This is what I have tried:-
(SELECT 
  ps5_game, COUNT(*) AS occ 
  FROM ps5 
  GROUP BY ps5_game
) 
UNION 
(SELECT 
  xbox_game, COUNT(*) AS occ 3
  FROM xbox 
  GROUP BY xbox_game
)
ORDER BY occ DESC

Now, the issue is that I do get the occurrences but this doesn't merge the occurrences of the same game. So, instead of GOW showing 4, I have the following:-



ps5_game
occ




GOW
1


COD
1


GOW
3



So, instead of adding the 1+3 from the two tables, it is being shown separately. Can anyone tell me how it can be achieved?

SELECT game, COUNT(*) AS occ
FROM (
  SELECT ps5_game AS game FROM ps5
 UNION ALL
  SELECT xbox_game FROM xbox
) as g
GROUP BY game
ORDER BY occ;

Output, tested on MySQL 8.4.3:
+------+-----+
| game | occ |
+------+-----+
| GTA  |   1 |
| PVZ  |   1 |
| COD  |   3 |
| UC   |   3 |
| GOW  |   4 |
+------+-----+


Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for!

This can be achieve by using a simple JOIN.
SELECT 
  ps5_game, COUNT(*) AS occ 
FROM ps5
JOIN 
  xbox ON xbox.xbox_game = ps5.ps5_game
GROUP BY ps5_game


Will give occ = 9 if there are 3 xbox_game and 3 ps5_game

Hey, thanks for that, but I believe there's an issue with the command above. It first says, Table 'test.xbox_game' doesn't exist. I replaced xbox_game after JOIN to match table name - xbox. Now, it says Unknown column 'xbox_game.xbox_game' in 'on clause'

I'm sorry, I read the table wrong. You also need to replace the table name in the on clause. Will edit this.
